# how to find data with Foreign key in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I  have three tables   Contact, ContactContactGroup, ContactGroups

```
 contact        contact_contact_group       contact_group
 contact_id     ccg_id                      contact_group_id 
 f_name         contact_id                  
 l_name         contact_group_id
```

I want to find all contacts with the group name with no repetition, for example, if (ali) is belongs to two group, so it should be display once while group name twice in which group it belongs, how can I do that? I tried a lot but didn't get success.

this is my query.

```
 $contact_group = $this->Contact->ContactsContactGroup->ContactGroup->find('all');
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not following the [Cake database conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)? Because that would be the easiest solution, unless this is a 3rd party/external database of course.

Comment: hmmm, I can define primary_id in model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
  $contact_group = $this->Contact->ContactsContactGroup->find('all');
```

it will get you all records with group name.

Comment: your query is working but the thing is that I still can't find the exact solution, like ali have defaultgroup and nicegroup.